# How to select items by providing where clause in pivot

Tags: sql, laravel, pivot, pivot-table, eloquent

This is my code looks like right now :

```
$result = Category::with(array(
            "getProducts",
            "getProducts.getBrand",
            "getProducts.getImages",
            "getProducts.getDetail",
            "getProducts.getTax",
            "getProducts.getDiscount",
            "getProducts.getAttributes" => function($query) use($_temp){
                if($_temp != null){
                    $query->where_in('attributes.id',$_temp);
                }
            },
            "getSlideshow",
            "getSlideshow.getItems",
            "getAttributeListing",
            "getAttributeListing.getAttributes",
            "getAttributeListing.getAttributes.productSpecific"
        ))
        ->where('id','=', $category_id)
        ->first();
```

Yet, It only filters the getProducts.getAttributes items not the 'getProducts' itself. Is there a way that I can get the Products by attributes?

Note: I am using Laravel 3

Comment: You might want to add a pivot tag.

Comment: I did try to find an example of this but can you show me how ?